# How do I make this diagram?

Tags: math-mode

How does one encode this into the XY-Pic package?

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as this site is not a _please do this for me_ service, plesae show the code you have so far. How to make curved arrows are even showed on the first page of `xy-guide.pdf`.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend `tikz-cd`, you can see why in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} % first solution

\usepackage{tikz-cd} % second solution

\begin{document}

\[ % xy
\xymatrix{
  A \ar[r]^f \ar@/_1.2pc/[rr]_{g\circ f} &
  B \ar[r]^g \ar@/^1.2pc/[rr]^{h\circ g} &
  C \ar[r]^h &
  D
}
\]

\[ % tikz-cd
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[rr,bend right,"g\circ f"'] &
  B \arrow[r,"g"] \arrow[rr,bend left,"h\circ g"] &
  C \arrow[r,"h"] &
  D
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the `graphs` and `quotes` library of `tikz`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary {graphs, quotes}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph {
    A ->["f"] B -> ["g"]C ->["h"]D;
    B -> [bend left,out=75,in=105, edge label=hog] D;
    A -> [bend right, edge label'=gof] C;
};

\end{document}
```